# export mysql table to csv with php (no select into outfile)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to export a MySQL table to a CSV file.
The code I have works fine:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `TABLE`'); 
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
$headers = array(); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{     
$headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i); 
} 
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
if ($fp && $result) 
{     
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');    
header('Expires: 0');
fputcsv($fp, $headers); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
}
die; 
}
```

However I would like to have the csv file uploaded automatically to my web host server instead of being downloaded to my computer.
I can't use the "SELECT... INTO OUTFILE" query as my provider does not want to give me the FILE privilege.
Any way I can wright the csv output to my provider's server with php instead of downloading it to my computer?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right, but why don't you fopen() a file directly in the filesystem, instead of using php://output? (I'm assuming that the php code is running in your provider's server)

Comment: Sounds like you're falling into the X/Y problem here asking the question that way. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem -- In any case, instead of `'php://output'` just specify the filename on disk if you want to store it to the server. The functions used in your example just work as documented. Read in the manual about each one of those and remove those which are not necessary and give the correct parameters for those you'd like to command those functions to do your business. If you don't tell to store to the server, it won't store to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store on the server instead of offering the data to the browser, you need to do some changes with your (otherwise fine working) code:

1. The [`header` function](http://php.net/header) is not needed any longer. Remove those.
2. You don't want to output into [`php://output`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) any longer, but instead use the path to the file where you want to store the CSV data into.

And that's it already.

Some example code with the outdated Mysql client library you're using as PHP 5.5 code:

```
$file_name = '/path/to/file/on/server.csv';
$sql       = 'SELECT * FROM `TABLE`';

$query = function ($statement) {
    if (!$result = mysql_query($statement)) throw new RuntimeException(
        sprintf('Statement %s failed: #%s %s', var_export($statement, true), mysql_errno(), mysql_error())
    );
    return $result;
};

$names = function ($result) {
    for ($names = [], $i = mysql_num_fields($result); $i; $i--)
        $names[] = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
    return $names;
};

$rows = function($result) {while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) yield $row;};

$result = $query($sql);

$lines = new AppendIterator();
$lines->append(new ArrayIterator([$names($result)]));
$lines->append($rows($result));

$csv = new SplFileObject($file_name, 'w');
foreach ($lines as $fields) {
    $csv->fputcsv($fields);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. let's say I want to store the file into the same folder as the php file. What should I use instead of "$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); " ?

Comment: You would use: `__DIR__ . '/filename.csv'`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I spent my day on this and you finally gave me the last piece to my puzzle at midnight! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Seeing your question history a bit, consider learning about how to accept an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work